# Why does my nav not resize after removing class in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on this website since last week. It is a school project, and I can't figure out why part of it isn't working. When I scroll down, click on the menu button, leave the menu down, then scroll back up, the navbar keeps its height even though I take away the class that resized it. I have attempted to use Google Chrome's developer tools to see what is happening. It just shows the height property crossed out. I have no idea why it won't work, and I have looked for any reason in my code. I also tried it in Internet Explorer to see if chrome was just having problems with it for some reason. It did the same thing there causing me to assume the problem is in my code.

Here is a link to the website it is currently published on: http://www.dragonmath.net/rockets/

Html Code:
http://www.dragonmath.net/rockets/index.html

Javascript Code:
http://www.dragonmath.net/rockets/javascript/main.js

CSS Sheet 1:
http://www.dragonmath.net/rockets/styles/main.css

CSS Sheet 2:
http://www.dragonmath.net/rockets/styles/function.css

Comment: I couldn't see a problem! would you please take a screenshot of what you mean?!

Comment: Try this: http://www.dragonmath.net/pics/capture.png

Comment: That is after pressing menu, then scrolling back up. It led to that where the height is crossed out.

Comment: You might have some `javascript` or `jquery` to display `nav` or `hide` it when you `scrollTop`?? If yes!! Please post it!!

Comment: The javascript to display the nave when I scroll to the top should be on the javascript page: http://www.dragonmath.net/rockets/javascript/main.js

Comment: It is in the window.on(click) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got problem!!
After scrolling back to top you didn't change height of `nav` element;after scroll back make it 40px again it may solve your problem.

```
if (flag !== 2 && $(window).scrollTop() === 0) {

        //add this line
        $nav.css({height:'40px'});

        $nav.slideUp();
        $nav.removeClass("dropDown");
        $menu.stop(true,false).slideUp(800, function () {
            $heading.css({'margin-left':'40px'})
        });
        $nav.stop(true,false).slideDown();
        flag = 2;
    }
```

Comment: I had tried that, but it didn't do anything. This is the code: $nav.css({'height':'40px'}); Is that how you would do it or am I doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Also, I would think that it should have resized it anyway after I took away the dropDown class.

Comment: Thanks, so why did it not work when I added it below the top, because I had added that same line below the $nav.removeClass("dropDown"); and it hadn't worked. I am fairly new to JQuery, so I am curious to why the placement matters.